# Limit for $x\to\pi$ for the trigonometric function $(1+\cos x)/\tan^2x$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{1+\cos x}{\tan^2x}$

How would I be able to solve this without using L'Hôpital's rule?

I have tried everything with normal identity manipulation etc and I have finally come to the decision it must be done somehow with the sandwich theorem but can't exactly see how.

I struggle to apply The squeeze/sandwich/ pinch theorem on limits with a trig in the numerator.

Comment: Trig expressions often simplify when you put everything in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, as in the Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\frac{1+\cos x}{\tan^2x}=\frac{\cos^2x(1+\cos x)}{\sin^2x}=\frac{\cos^2x(1+\cos x)}{1-\cos^2x}=\frac{\cos^2x}{1-\cos x}$$

which is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: @fred You are welcome! You were on the right track. In general that's a good method when possible. When it leads to some cancellation of terms which goes to $0$ (in that case $1+\cos x$) there are good chances that the method is effective.

Comment: Something to look out for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\cos(\pi-t)=-\cos t$ and $\tan(\pi-t)=-\tan t$, so the limit becomes, with $x=\pi-t$,
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\cos t}{\tan^2t}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(1-\cos t)(1+\cos t)}{\sin^2t}\frac{\cos^2t}{1+\cos t}
$$

Now, having seen this, we could do the trick directly:
$$
\frac{1+\cos x}{\tan^2x}=
\frac{(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}{\sin^2x}\frac{\cos^2x}{1-\cos x}
$$

Comment: (+1) This is just what I was writing up.

Comment: In that case it suffices a simpler manipulation using trig identities.

Comment: @gimusi Yes, of course. But in many cases transforming into a limit at $0$ makes things simpler.

Comment: @egreg Yes I agree with you, often that the best way to avoid confusion or mistakes but in that particular case using trig identities is a more straightforward method in my opinion.

Comment: @gimusi I valued your comment and added the hint

Comment: @egreg Thanks! That's a good method to indicate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $1 + \tan^2(x) = 1/\cos^2(x)$ (divide trig identity by $cos^2(x)$)

Your expression turns into

$\lim_{x \to\pi}\frac{(cos(x)+1)*cos^2(x)}{1 - cos^2(x)}$

Can you progress from there?

Comment: Not sure what you did then, the difference of squares formula and the identity of $cos(\pi)$ is all you need ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1**

Note, that

- $\lim\limits_{x\to \pi}\tan x= \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\tan x$
- $\lim\limits_{x\to \pi}\cos x= \lim\limits_{x\to 0}-\cos x$

**Hint 2**

$1-\cos x = 2 \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$

**Hint 3**

$\lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha}=1$